# What can go wrong (what are the risks) if i don't escape the data and insert it to database?

Tags: database, codeigniter, insert, escaping

I am using codeigniter and in security section it suggest that: Escape the data before submitting it into your database or outputting it to a browser.

What could really go wrong if I don't escape it, what are the risks?

Thank you.

Comment: you should have asked this question at https://security.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

**Major Threats**

1. [SQL Injection](https://www.acunetix.com/websitesecurity/sql-injection/)
2. [Cross Side Request Forgery](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF))

Comment: Thank you Malik, however I have enabled the global xss filtering and I am using the Active record, do I still need to use the $this->db->escape()?

Comment: You are all good . Read first answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13125707/codeigniter-active-record-when-to-escape-if-at-all

Comment: First - that answer is not correct. You are prone to CSRF even if you escape your SQL queries (CSRF and SQL injection are two different and independent threats). 
Second - I really love Codeigniter, but it has one of the worst naming conventions. XSS filtering should do nothing with database input sanitization. 
Third - if you are using Active record, your queries are sanitized.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Active Record, you don't need to escape the data before inserting into the database. You should still be validating it, though.

If you later echo()/print() the values in a view, however, you should escape to avoid XSS: $this->security->xss_clean().

Global XSS filtering is deprecated and should no longer be used.

You should also enable CSRF protection in your config if you have any forms on your application.

You can read more about all of this here: https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/security.html

Comment: Thank you @versalle88 for pointing out the global XSS filtering deprecation.